# I got View [index] not found. error in custom plugin

Tags: laravel

Making custom plugin with “QuizzesInit” name I have problems, I suppose because of double names plugin.
My plugin is located in /projects_path/quizzes/packages/vendorname/QuizzesInit/src/Providers/QuizzesInitProvider.php file and has content:

```
<?php

// My phpstorm shows error here : Namespace name doesn't match the PSR-0/PSR-4 project structure

    namespace vendorname\QuizzesInit\Providers;
    
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
    
    class QuizzesInitProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * Bootstrap services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {
            $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/../routes/web.php');
    
            $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/views', 'QuizzesInit' );
        }
    
        public function register()
        {
    
        }
    }
```

Adding route in /projects_path/quizzes/packages/vendorname/QuizzesInit/src/routes/web.php :

```
Route::get('/quizzes', function () {
    //packages/vendorname/QuizzesInit/src/views/index.blade.php
    return view('QuizzesInit::index');
}); // ->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');
```

I got error on url "http://local-site.com/quizzes"

```
View [index] not found.
```

I do not know is this error is related with “QuizzesInit” name and Namespace name  breaking PSR-0/PSR-4 project structure I show in my provider ?

In all docs (like https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/packages#service-providers) in 1 word plugin names are used...

How can it be fixed ?

**UPDATED INFO # 1:**
At docs https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/packages#service-providers that is not clear actually which composer commands I need to run

1. I  run

   composer init

in clear vendorname/QuizzesInit directory
and created new composer project

2. I run in project root :

   composer dump-autoload

with success, but it did not show my package

3. when I run composer require with my package in project root :

   $ composer require vendorname\QuizzesInit

   In PackageDiscoveryTrait.php line 364:

   Could not find a matching version of package vendornameQuizzesInit. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev).
4. in composer.json I have :

   "autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
   "App\": "app/",
   "Database\Factories\": "database/factories/",
   "vendorname\QuizzesInit\": "packages/vendorname/QuizzesInit/src/",
   "Database\Seeders\": "database/seeders/"
   }
   },

5)Inside of my /packages/vendorname/QuizzesInit/src I have files :

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   585 Feb 14 08:47 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 95971 Feb 14 07:34 composer.lock
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Feb 14 07:35 Providers
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Feb 14 08:53 routes
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Feb 14 07:34 src
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Feb 14 07:34 vendor
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Feb 15 06:39 views
```

But am not sure now which command did I run, I run differend commands in root dir and /packages/vendorname/QuizzesInit...
I found in net some step by step manuals(like https://adevait.com/laravel/how-to-create-a-custom-package-for-laravel),
but it is somewhat confusing for me, which commands have I to run at first and during development of the package ?

**UPDATED INFO # 2 :**

In packages/vendorname/QuizzesInit/src/routes/web.php I added :

```
 Route::get('/quizzes_count', function () {
    return 'quizzes_count';
});
```

So running http://local-com.com/quizzes_count
I got valid 'quizzes_count' string in my browse, so I think my plugin is installed correctly and in
provider file packages/vendorname/QuizzesInit/src/Providers/QuizzesInitProvider.php   having 2 options :

```
 public function boot()
{
    $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/../routes/web.php');
    // routes with line above works ok
 
 
    // view with line below does not work at all
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/views', 'QuizzesInit' );
}
```

?

**UPDATED INFO # 3 :**

```
# Project/packages/vendorname/QuizzesInit/src/views$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Feb 15 06:39 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Feb 15 06:39 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  643 Feb 15 06:40 index.blade.php
```

**UPDATED INFO # 4:**
I write

```
__DIR__ . '/views'
```

value into log on and have :

```
Project/packages/vendorname/QuizzesInit/src/Providers/views
```

But it is different from real path :

```
Project/packages/vendorname/QuizzesInit/src/views/index.blade.php
```

Where from "Providers/"? Or have I to add this "Providers/" subdirectory in my options? Where ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the [PSR standards](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/#:~:text=This%20PSR%20describes%20a%20specification,autoloaded%20according%20to%20the%20specification.)? _Alphabetic characters in the fully qualified class name MAY be any combination of lower case and upper case._ Are you actually using `vendorname` in the using?

Comment: yes vendorname is in lower case. Is it a problem ?

Comment: It shouldn't even though it is not conventional. But you haven't installed this using composer?

Comment: I fixed issue with PSR, but view is not found yet. UPDATED INFO # 1:

Comment: Please read UPDATED INFO # 2

Comment: Show `Views` directory please.

Comment: In UPDATED INFO # 3

Comment: This all looks fine, only thing I can think of is that somehow, `__DIR__ . '/views'` is not the right path..

Comment: That is the point! Please read UPDATED INFO # 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes a lot of sense after all the info you've supplied.

`$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/views', 'QuizzesInit' );` is located in `packages/vendorname/QuizzesInit/src/Providers/QuizzesInitProvider.php`

If you look up what the documentation says about `__DIR__`, *Returns the directory of the file.*, it will all make sense.

Your `QuizzesInitProvider.php` is located in `packages/vendorname/QuizzesInit/src/Providers`, so that's what `__DIR__` will return to you.

However, you are looking for the `Views` directory, which is not under `/Providers`, but one step up,
So in order to get to the `Views` directory, you have to do exactly the same thing you did with the routes (can't believe neither of us spotted this sooner), so `$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/views', 'QuizzesInit' );` will now become `$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../views', 'QuizzesInit' );` with the dots signifying that you want to move one directory up from the current directory (`/Providers`) and then move into the `/views` directory.

*TL;DR:*

Change: `$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/views', 'QuizzesInit' );`

to: `$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../views', 'QuizzesInit' );`